# How to create logical variable based on logical condition?

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have a data frame with factor variables

```
> a <- c("a", "b", "c")
> b <- c("c", "b", "a")
> df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a,b))
> df$a <- as.factor(df$a)
> df$b <- as.factor(df$b)
> df
  a b
1 a c
2 b b
3 c a
```

I create new logical variable based on the similarity of var a and var b.

```
> df$result <- isTRUE(df$a == df$b)
```

But I get the result:

```
> df
  a b result
1 a c  FALSE
2 b b  FALSE
3 c a  FALSE
```

When I expected

```
> df
  a b result
  1 a c  FALSE
  2 b b  TRUE
  3 c a  FALSE
```

(I'm using factors to replicate my real data)

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve my goal of identifying similar variables? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
df$result <- with(df, a==b)
df
#  a b result
#1 a c  FALSE
#2 b b   TRUE
#3 c a  FALSE
```

The `a==b` already returns a logical vector and we don't need `isTRUE` to wrap it.

As @Frank mentioned in the comments, it is better to evaluate between `character` class columns as difference in `factor` levels can result in error.  We can either convert the `factor` to `character` for evaluating

```
 with(df, as.character(a)==as.character(b))
```

or make the levels the same as in both columns

```
 Un1 <- union(levels(df$a), levels(df$b))
 df[] <- lapply(df, factor, levels=Un1)
 with(df, a==b)
```

Comment: Great thanks @akrun, This works! Is with() reliable to be used within a function?

Comment: @jpinelo I guess it should work.  I used `with` to avoid calling `df$` everytime.  BTW, if you are using this inside a function, avoid usign `$` and instead use `[`

Comment: of course. Already tried but have to wait 11 min from 1st answer.

Comment: Worth emphasizing: factors are the worst. Suppose you had arrived at `df` in this way: `df = data.frame(a=c("A",a),b=c("a",b))[-1, ]`. Then R would refuse to evaluate `with(df, a==b)`.